# How to read HDFS file from Scala code

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am new to Scala and HDFS:

I am just wondering I am able to read local file from Scala code but how to read from HDFS:

```
import scala.io.source
object ReadLine {
  def main(args:Array[String]) {
    if (args.length>0) {
      for (line <- Source.fromLine(args(0)).getLine())
        println(line)
      }
    }
```

in Argument I have passed `hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/log_data/file1..` But its giving `FileNotFoundException` error 
I am definitely missing something.. can anyone help me out here ?

Answer (score 10):

`scala.io.source` api cannot read from `HDFS`. `Source` is used to read from local file system.

**Spark**

If you want to read from `hdfs` then I would recommend to use `spark` where you would have to use `sparkContext`.

```
val lines = sc.textFile(args(0))  //args(0) should be hdfs:///usr/local/log_data/file1
```

**No Spark**

If you don't want to use `spark` then you should go with `BufferedReader` or `StreamReader` or `hadoop filesystem api`. for example

```
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(new URI("hdfs://yourUrl:port/"), new Configuration()) 
val path = new Path("/path/to/file/")
val stream = hdfs.open(path)
def readLines = Stream.cons(stream.readLine, Stream.continually( stream.readLine))
```